# How do I get bash info nodes on the ubuntu terminal?

Tags: ubuntu, bash, info

When I'm on my phones terminal termux and I run the command`bash info` I get The GNU Bash Reference Manual info nodes . Yet then I run the same command on my ubuntu terminal all I get is the man pages from the info command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're in a separate `bash-doc` package:

```
$ apt-file search bash.info
bash-doc: /usr/share/info/bash.info.gz
```

Comment: Yo thank you!! All I had to do was `sudo apt install bash-doc`. Great answer.

Answer (score 1):

Update and install like this:

```
$ sudo apt-file update


$ sudo apt-file search bash.info


$ sudo apt install bash-doc
```

Comment: You could improve your answer by providing references or citations